# how can I send header with each methods of wsdl in zeep?

Tags: python, python-3.x, header, wsdl, zeep

I'm new to use zeep. and trying implement a  wsdl:http://leon.leonardotravel.com/Leon.svc/wsdl

i have to send request like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <Search xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Header>
        <AgentId>agentid</AgentId>
        <Password>password</Password>
        <Username>username</Username>
      </Header>
      <Search>
        <CheckIn>2017-06-10</CheckIn>
        <CheckOut>2017-06-12</CheckOut>
        <CityId>4339</CityId>
        <CurrencyId>2</CurrencyId>
        <HotelId>122079</HotelId>
        <PaxCountryId>2</PaxCountryId>
        <DefaultPhotoInclude>false</DefaultPhotoInclude>
        <GeoCoordinatesInclude>false</GeoCoordinatesInclude>
        <HotelAddressInclude>false</HotelAddressInclude>
        <HotelDescriptionInclude>false</HotelDescriptionInclude>
        <HotelNameInclude>true</HotelNameInclude>
        <MaxResponseTime>0</MaxResponseTime>
        <SearchRooms>
          <SearchRoom>
            <Adult>1</Adult>
            <Child1Age>0</Child1Age>
            <Child2Age>0</Child2Age>
            <Child3Age>0</Child3Age>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          </SearchRoom>
        </SearchRooms>
      </Search>
    </Search>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I should send header when i wanna to use each methods of this wsdl.
can you help me?!

Comment: What you're trying to do is not clear.

Comment: I want to implement a wsdl in python

Comment: Did you try something ? show some code your working on.

Comment: Sending header in every request can be achieved using Plugins in zeep. See documentation http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/plugins.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since google lead me here, I'll post my findings.

In order to send the same SOAP headers on every call a client makes, I did this, with some silly replacements for general consumption:

```
from zeep import Client, xsd
client = Client(
    wsdl_url,
    transport=transport,
)

header = xsd.ComplexType(
    xsd.Sequence([
        xsd.Element('SomeString', xsd.String()),
        xsd.Element('SomeBoolean', xsd.Boolean()),
    ])
)

headers = [ header(SomeString='Hello', SomeBoolean=True) ]
client.set_default_soapheaders(headers)

client.service.MakeTheMagic(Stuff=stuff)
```